# Tor not making connection to the network

Tags: windows

In Windows XP, after long history of correct wotking without problems, there is one now. After run a "Start Tor Browser.exe", a window "connecting to the Tor Network" shows up but the progress bar don`t change. Nothing is going on. After a while there is problem with this window, it changes to white without any letters. In process menager the tor.exe is present, in the firewall window tor.exe is sending and receiving packets, but the tor browser is not openning.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue at the moment.... I'm a Tor noob, so starting afresh here. I'm guessing there is a way to trigger a log file being created but I cant find how. Currently I'm trying to get Vidalia going as I've read that I can look at logs there. However, elsewhere I've read that Vidalia will only run once a connection has been established so it may be a wrong road to go down - but no worries, I'm learning from these issues :-) And its nice being a noob at something lol. My setup is an XP box (actually a VM hosted by VBox) with firewall disabled, Vipre AV (temporarily disabled) an

Comment: What version do you use?